# Trinidad2.0.1 not working with IE11

Tags: jsf-2, trinidad

I am using trinindad-2.0.1 with JSF2.0 and it is working fine with IE8 browser. I tried to use same application in IE11 but I am getting following exception when try to use the application:

java.lang.NullPointerException at
org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.ui.RootRenderingContext.getRendererManager.

There is an open and unresolved query in Trinidad for this:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TRINIDAD-2451

Can any one let me know which version of trinidad and JSF combination should be used for IE11?

Comment: Try with the latest version: 2.1.0

Answer (score 4):

There are some workarounds to make version 2.0.1 to work with IE9+, implementing a custom filter for example:

http://jonasdegraaff.blogspot.com.es/2013/11/how-to-run-your-adf-111x-application.html

But the latest stable version (2.1.0+) works with IE9+. The official download page is finally updated with it:

https://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/download.html

You can also download it from here:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.myfaces.trinidad/

Comment: Wow, thank you! It will be useful for our legacy applications!